# How to handle nested Futures Sequence functions in Scala

Tags: scala, future

I'd like to create a function that returns the results of a sequence of futures that has been manipulated on success. The issue I'm having is that the return type is of Unit and the future function is completing without waiting for the nested future sequence to finish. I've tried not using the onComplete function and instead map or flatMap but have had no success. I'd also like to avoid using an await

```
class SquareGenerator(){
  //if type is changed to Unit anything that calls this function receives a empty success
  def getSquare() : Future[Int] = Future{
    val sums = List(future1(), future2())

    val results = Future.sequence(sums)

    //compiler throws an error because this is returning a unit
    results.onComplete({ 
      case Success(result) =>{
        val sum = result(0) + result(1)
        sum * sum
      }
    })
  }

  private def future1() : Future[Int] = Future{
    //do something that takes time
    2
  }

  private def future2() : Future[Int] = Future{
    //do something that takes time
    3
  }
}
```

This would be later called like so

```
val squareGenerator = new SquareGenerator()
squareGenerator.getSquare().onComplete({
  case Success(result) =>{
    //do something with result
  }
  case Failure(e){//log failure}
})
```

Comment: I think you mean `map` rather than `onComplete`

Comment: One of the quirks of using Future is that once you use It in one place, you have to use it everywhere if you don't want to block for the result of the Future with an Await. If you want to extract the result of the Future, there is no way to avoid blocking on the Future. The alternative is to keep the result in the Future context and use successive calls to map and flatMap to manipulate the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `onComplete` you should do:

```
results.map{ result => 
                val sum = result(0) + result(1)
                sum * sum
            }.recover { case e => ...
                // write to log, throw e, or return the same type of sum
}
```

with `map` you can convert the return type inside the `Future`, and the future will be returned only if it's finished successfully.

That's why you need to add `recover` to handle the case where the future fails.

If you will do that, you won't need the `Future` at the beginning of the function, because you don't need to create a new `Future` - you will use the `Future` from `results`.

Comment: this throws a compilation error : Expression of type Future[Int] doesn't conform to expected type T_

Comment: yes, it's because I didn't complete the `recover` part and left a comment for you to finish. If you will do `recover{ case e => 0} it will compile`. BTW - you don't need to begin with Future at the start of the function (editing and adding it to my answer)

Answer (score 1):

`onComplete` produces a `Unit`. You want `map` or `flatMap` or something else that actually produces a value.

```
  def getSquare() : Future[Int] = {
    val sums = List(future1(), future2())

    val results: Future[List[Int]] = Future.sequence(sums)

    results.map {
      result => 
        val sum = result(0) + result(1)
        sum * sum
    }
  }
```

Using array indexes is not safe. You could use a fold or pattern matching for safety.

```
    results map {
      case m :: n :: Nil =>
        val sum = m + n
        sum * sum
      case _ =>
        println("did not get 2 numbers!")
        0
    }
```

Comment: This does not fix the issue where the initial call to squareGenerator.getSquare() is  still returning an empty result because it's not waiting for the nested future to complete

Comment: That is again because you are using `onComplete` - use `map` and `recover` or something else - what do you want `val square` to be?

Answer (score 0):

just return future here

```
def getSquare : Future[Future[List[Int]]] = Future{
    val sums = List(future1(), future2())
    Future.sequence(sums)
  }
```

and, when you call it, check onComplete of result

```
  squareGenerator.getSquare.onComplete({
    case Success(result) =>
      result.onComplete({
        case Success(result) => {
          val sum = result(0) + result(1)
          val square = sum * sum
          println(square)
        }
      })

    case Failure(e) => {
      //log failure
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use map/flatmap or for comprehension.

```
def getSquare() : Future[Int] = 
  for {
    res1 <- future1()
    res2 <- future2()
  } yield {
    val sum = res1 + res2
    sum * sum
  }
```

`for comprehension` is a convenient wrapper around map and flatmap. In `for` section you need to assign results of futures to variables and later you can oparate on them in `yield` section.